# Notification of changes when writing a comment

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, deleted-comments

So, I noticed earlier on Stack Overflow while writing a comment in reply to an erroneous comment to my answer that was deleted while writing the reply, but the site had not notified me.

I posted a reply and in the meantime a comment from the same (probably replying about what I had just said to a now non-existent comment) user posted apologizing for the confusion, and I posted my comment. I quickly removed my reply to his now non-existent comment and was going to leave a different one, but then his comment was deleted in the meantime -- which I accidentally replied to as well and had to quickly delete!

It's a bit of a usability issue that caused a slight ping-pong of comment creation and deleting that was confusing to say the least. Granted, it is a bit of an edge case where both users need to be active and looking at the same issue at the same time, but I still think there should have been something to notify me that a comment that I may have been replying to was just deleted (or even edited?) while I was writing one.

Perhaps it did give me a notification, but I simply had not seen it. Sorry in that case!

Comment: I have experienced the same problem, multiple times on fresh questions where it is quite likely that OP is online and answering quickly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not a bug as there is no feature to notify you if a comment gets deleted.

Comments are not considered to be important. For that reason users shouldn't get to much attached to it. As comments are mainly used to get clarification they become obsolete rather quickly. As you experienced even so quickly that the comment thread becomes stale at an instant.

This comment confusion you ran into is only occurring on certain posts (and I tend to believe that on meta itself this might be more of an issue than on main) so your future request for comments change notification only add value on a few posts. Let me also point out that comments are not threaded, so the system doesn't know if you're responding to a previous comment. This is very much by-design.

Users have enough tools to easily self-moderate their comments as soon as they see a mistake is made and/or flag comments that are obsolete or too chatty.

I therefor think we don't need this feature with the next 6-8 weeks.

Comment: It created confusion which did rise out of an an admittedly sparse scenario of pure chance which I thought qualified the bug tag. It seemed like incorrect behavior either way.

Comment: @Ragora it's a very minor confusion, and easily rectified.

Comment: @BillWoodger Yea, it is. I suppose I more or less wanted to see what was thought of it.